# Says that the table does not exist in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting the following error:

```
08-04 20:31:10.788  30724-30724/com.lifttrackplus.jason.lifttrackplus 

E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: exercise_data_table
08-04 20:31:10.799  30724-30724/com.lifttrackplus.jason.lifttrackplus E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting date=2015-08-04 name=bench press repCount=1 setCount=1 weight=1
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: exercise_data_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO exercise_data_table(date,name,repCount,setCount,weight) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1527)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1399)
            at com.lifttrackplus.jason.lifttrackplus.ExerciseDataDBHelper.addRow(ExerciseDataDBHelper.java:56)
            at com.lifttrackplus.jason.lifttrackplus.AddExerciseInstanceActivity.onClick(AddExerciseInstanceActivity.java:79)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19919)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5499)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

Here are the .java files

DBContract.java

```
public class DBContract implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_DATA = "exercise_data_table";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME_LIST = "exercise_name_table";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LIST_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATA_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATA_WEIGHT = "weight";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATA_SET = "setCount";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATA_REP = "repCount";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATA_DATE = "date";

}
```

ExerciseDataDBHelper.java

```
public class ExerciseDataDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "ListDBHelper";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exercise_data.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String NUM_TYPE = " INTEGER";
    private static final String STRING_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ", ";

    private static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBContract.TABLE_NAME_DATA;
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.TABLE_NAME_DATA + "(" +
            DBContract._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_NAME + STRING_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_WEIGHT + NUM_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_SET + NUM_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_REP + NUM_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_DATE + STRING_TYPE + ")";

    public ExerciseDataDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Table created");
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DELETE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    public void addRow(SQLiteDatabase db, Exercise exercise) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_NAME, exercise.getNAME());
        contentValues.put(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_WEIGHT, exercise.getWEIGHT());
        contentValues.put(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_SET, exercise.getSET());
        contentValues.put(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_REP, exercise.getREP());
        contentValues.put(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_DATE, exercise.getDATE());
        db.insert(DBContract.TABLE_NAME_DATA, null, contentValues);
    }

    public Exercise exerciseByName(SQLiteDatabase db, String name) {
        Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.TABLE_NAME_DATA + " WHERE " + DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_NAME + "=" + "'" + name + "'", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            exercise.setNAME(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_NAME)));
            exercise.setWEIGHT(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_WEIGHT)));
            exercise.setSET(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_SET)));
            exercise.setREP(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_REP)));
            exercise.setDATE(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATA_DATE)));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return exercise;
    }

}
```

AddExerciseInstanceActivity.java

```
public class AddExerciseInstanceActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button addInstanceButton;
    private Button toGraphButton;
    private EditText weight;
    private EditText set;
    private EditText rep;
    private ExerciseDataDBHelper dataDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_exercise_instance);

        addInstanceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_exercise_instance_btn);
        toGraphButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.to_graph_btn);
        weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        set = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set);
        rep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rep);

        dataDBHelper = new ExerciseDataDBHelper(AddExerciseInstanceActivity.this);
        db = dataDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        addInstanceButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        toGraphButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddExerciseInstanceActivity.this, ExerciseGraphActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add_exercise_instance, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
        exercise.setNAME(getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME"));
        exercise.setWEIGHT(Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString()));
        exercise.setSET(Integer.parseInt(set.getText().toString()));
        exercise.setREP(Integer.parseInt(rep.getText().toString()));
        exercise.setDATE(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date()));

        dataDBHelper.addRow(db, exercise);

        dataDBHelper.close();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

I have already tried uninstalling the app and restarting Android Studio, but I keep getting the same error. Is it the `CREATE_TABLE String` because that seems to be the standard issue but I cannot see what is wrong with my statement. I know that this will probably be a stupid little error. I started the project this morning and I think that it needs a set of fresh eyes. Thank you.

Comment: chances are you just need to update the database version. did you ever change the table name?

Comment: I get an error when I try to update the version, says that I cannot downgrade from 2 to 1

Comment: yes? because, like it says, you can't downgrade. only upgrade.

Comment: Incrementing really means `increase by n`: you should **up**grade from version 2 to **3**, not decrement to 1...

Answer (score 0):

Two things off the top of my head:

1. In your create statement, I think you need to have a space between the table name and the open parenthesis.
2. After you make a change like in #1, or if you suspect corruption in your database and want to start over again, increment your database version number. `onUpgrade` will be called, and in your `onUpgrade` you just delete and recreate the table. You (and anyone using your app) will lose all the data in the table if you do this, but since right now you can't use it anyway you might as well. For this reason, once you're in production it is advisable to use cascading `if` statements in `onUpgrade` to make non-destructive updates to your database if you need to change something, like adding a column or table.

Comment: when I increment the database version it gives me an error saying that I cannot downgrade from version 2 to 1

Comment: @internetRando Well, **incrementing** really means the **opposite**: you should **up**grade from version **2** to **3**.

Comment: `In your create statement, I think you need to have a space between the table name and the open parenthesis` No, it's optional. Only needed for readability

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is nothing wrong with this code. I copied and pasted the code into another class and edited it, but i forgot to change the DATABASE_NAME in the new helper class...I knew it was something stupid like that.